# More hours in the gym

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding

Does spending more hours in the gym makes you getting bulkier and reach the body you after faster?
I know that rest is needed to get bulkier but if I exercise the same muscle over and over in the same day, does that make it getting bigger faster?

I have seen a report about a big transformation for a fat guy in 6 months, as he was spending long hours in gym

http://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/fitness/weight-loss/how-a-12-million-bet-helped-this-guy-lose-weight/news-story/8d66b48a3f3b686e1f828e11dacaf6b4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, no. With body transformations there are no shortcuts, you just have to put in the work. And  that *work* consists of three parts: train, rest and eat.

Train hard, rest (and sleep) a lot, and eat to support your goals.